# SQL запрос на получение истории переписки

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть 2 таблицы, `messages(id_msg, text, from_id(от кого сообщение), to_id(кому сообщение))` и `users(id_user, name)`.

`from_id, to_id` - Внешние ключи, которые ссылаются на первичный ключ `id_user`, таблицы `users`

Как можно составить запрос на получение истории сообщений, по принципу как в ВК.

То есть, есть список пользователей, нужно чтобы имя пользователя, который отправил последнее сообщение, был выше всех.

Попытался сделать так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.name from users
JOIN message ON users.id_user = message.from_id OR users.id_user = message.to_id
WHERE (from_id = 4) OR (to_id = 4)
/*ORDER BY (message.id_msg) */
```

Где цифра `4` означает `id` владельца переписки.
Но запрос работает не как задумано. Думаю, если закомментчиная строка работала, то запрос был бы верный.

Comment: Покажите структуру таблиц.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в вашем запросе заключается в том, что `ORDER BY` отрабатывает в самый последний момент, после всех остальных операций запроса. Вы пишите `select distinct`, от множества записей по пользователю он оставит одну (произвольную) и получать из нее дату сообщения для сортировки, когда до нее дойдет дело, уже не будет иметь смысла.

Вам надо приметить явную группировку по пользователю (distinct в принципе тот же group by, только неявный) и получить для группы максимальный id, после чего уже сортировать по нему (и по убыванию, что бы последнее было первым):

```
SELECT users.name
  from users
  JOIN message ON users.id_user = message.from_id OR users.id_user = message.to_id
 WHERE (from_id = 4) OR (to_id = 4)
 GROUP BY users.name
 ORDER BY max(message.id_msg) desc
```

Comment: Спасибо. А можно как-то вывести все записи из `users` в место `users.name` ?

Comment: @Данил `select users.*`

Comment: Пробовал, выдаёт `[42803] ERROR: column "users.id_user" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: Прошу прощения, забыл, что в postgres в GROUP BY тоже нужно добавить все поля

Comment: @Данил Ах, да, у вас же postgress ... Придется явно перечислить в `group by` все колонки из users, которые вас интересуют и их же писать в select. ну либо в select брать от колонок min/max, что по трудоемкости примерно то же